# boundary timer event in subprocess

Tags: subprocess, activiti

I have created a workflow which contain a subprocess with boundary timer. Here is my code:

```
 <process id="processsub" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" name="start" activiti:initiator="initiator"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="usertask1" activiti:assignee="${initiator}">
      <documentation>this is user task</documentation>
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="consult" name="Do u want to consult??" type="enum">
          <activiti:value id="true" name="true"></activiti:value>
          <activiti:value id="false" name="false"></activiti:value>
        </activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <subProcess id="subpro" name="subpro">
      <startEvent id="substart" name="substart"></startEvent>
      <userTask id="usertask2" name="usertask2" activiti:candidateGroups="doctor">
        <documentation>This is a user task for consultation..</documentation>
      </userTask>
      <userTask id="usertask3" name="usertask3" activiti:candidateGroups="doctor">
        <documentation>This is a user task for prescription</documentation>
      </userTask>
      <endEvent id="subend" name="subend"></endEvent>
      <parallelGateway id="par1" name="par1"></parallelGateway>
      <parallelGateway id="par2" name="par2"></parallelGateway>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow3" name="flow3" sourceRef="substart" targetRef="par1"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow4" name="flow4" sourceRef="par1" targetRef="usertask2"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow5" name="flow5" sourceRef="par1" targetRef="usertask3"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow6" name="flow6" sourceRef="usertask2" targetRef="par2"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow7" name="flow7" sourceRef="usertask3" targetRef="par2"></sequenceFlow>
      <sequenceFlow id="flow8" name="flow8" sourceRef="par2" targetRef="subend"></sequenceFlow>
    </subProcess>
    <endEvent id="end" name="end"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" name="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" name="flow2" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="subpro"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow9" name="flow9" sourceRef="subpro" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
    <boundaryEvent id="sid-FFAB6E5A-5E94-4001-9845-4D481E157F03" attachedToRef="subpro" cancelActivity="true">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT2M</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask4" name="usertask4" activiti:candidateGroups="reviewer"></userTask>
    <endEvent id="finalend" name="finalend"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow10" name="flow10" sourceRef="sid-FFAB6E5A-5E94-4001-9845-4D481E157F03" targetRef="usertask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow11" name="flow11" sourceRef="usertask4" targetRef="finalend"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
```

the timer getting fire after 2 minutes whether the subprocess got completed or it is partially completed i.e. 1 usertask got completed and second is incompleted. I want that if the subprocess got start whether it is completed or partially completed, the timer would not fire.
how i can do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do is to "cancel" a timer boundary event when a user task is completed. Unfortunately, it is not possible unless you code it via the API
The best way to do it is :

- transform your timer boundary event to a timer intermediate catch event
- when a user task is completed, send a "cancel" signal to the timer intermediate catch event
- to implement the cancel signal, you have to create an event gateway after which you wait for the "cancel" signal or a timer event

You process will be like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl9GC.png

Comment: can you provide some example for sending signal i.e. how to throw and catch signals in workflow process...please..:-)

Comment: You can do this by Java API
`runtimeService.messageEventReceived(messageName, executionId);` for message and `runtimeService.signalEventReceived(signalName, executionId);`for signal